# Populating a Razor Second Drop-down List from a List<object> in MVC based on First Filter without any Web API calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have one ViewModel "Grocery" with some Objects (like Apple, Orange, Chilly). And each objects has some properties and values. The problem is, there will be a first drop-down which will allow users to choose a color and based on the user selection it will populate the second drop-down list which displays the list after filtering (of the user selection). So, the scenario is like the following image:

[image]

Note: for image "Output" means the second drop-down. Sorry, forgot to mark into the picture.

I completed the ViewModel part till now and this view model is used by other part of the programs. So, I am trying to use Razor with jQuery which will solve the filtering issue and will update the list. My razor file looks like the following:

```
@{
    var model = (GroceryViewModel)Model.Model;  
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => model.ColorFilter, model.ColorFilterSelectList)

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => model.Grocery, 
                      new SelectList(model.Grocery, "DropDownTitle", "DropDownTitle", model.Degrees.First().DropDownTitle))
```

Using the above code snippets, I can populate the first drop-down. But for second drop-down, it is not giving the correct filtered data.

Do anybody know the proper way to solve this using some javascript or jQuery. Any types of suggestion is appreciated.

**I don't have any option to create any web api. So, I am thinking whether creating a global js object can solve this? I got lots of tutorial which is based on Web API. But the limitation is here, I cant use/create Web API. I don't know whether there is a better option or something ???**

Thanks

Comment: Refer also [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for a complete code example including the controller code necessary to use for editing existing objects so that you get correct 2-way model binding and client side validation

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I see you are using the web api. I dont have any option to create that api. I have the Model which holds all data. I am thinking to create a global javascript object/JSON and then call the model. I dont know whether it is the correct way or not.

Comment: What do you mean _web api_? Its a standard MVC project. And what do you mean by _create a global javascript object/JSON_?